Batch call through SafeSDK problems with "createTransaction"
I am trying to batch multiple transactions using createTransaction to save the user on clicking.
The problem is I'm getting errors on I believe because I'm doing something wrong when setting up the Safe.init()
This is a front-end facing code that I'm running via the Safe as a custom app at http://localhost:3001/ meaning my provider and signer come from window.ethereum rather than a private key.
Here is the code:
const iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(abi);
    const transactionData = iface.encodeFunctionData("claim", [index, recipient, value, merkleProof]); 

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
      `https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ALCHEMY_SEPOLIA_API_KEY}`
    );


    const safeSDK = await Safe.init({
      provider,
      safeAddress: address,
      signer
    });

    const transactions: MetaTransactionData = {
      to: CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
      value: "0",
      data: transactionData
    };

    const tx = await safeSDK.createTransaction({ transactions: [transactions] });

    const txHash = await safeSDK.getTransactionHash(tx);
    const approveTxResponse = await safeSDK.approveTransactionHash(txHash);
    await approveTxResponse.transactionResponse?.wait();

    const txResponse = await safeSDK.executeTransaction(tx);
    await txResponse.transactionResponse?.wait();

When running it I get the following error
TypeError: invalid EIP-1193 provider..
What exactly am I doing wrong? I have tried multiple ways to get the signer and provider both using wagmi and then the standard new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider way with no luck.

const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
// new
await Safe.init({
   provider: window.ethereum, // Or any compatible EIP-1193 provider
   signer: "0xSignerAddressOrPrivateKey", // Signer address or private key
   safeAddress: '0xSafeAddress'
   ...
})


doc: https://docs.safe.global/sdk/protocol-kit/guides/migrate-to-v4

thanks that seems to do it
